# Solving Inequalities - a curious observation

Tags: inequality

This question is about an interesting observation that comes up whenever one solves an inequality with a variable in the denominator.

eg.

1/x < 1

Why is it that, in the solution to these inequalities, x can be a values that are 1) on the outsides of the two critical values or 2) in between the two critical values?

I have never seen inequalities where x can take values in between both values AND on the outside of one critical value.

Another query: what is the formal, purely algebraic definition of a critical value (if there is one)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to format equations. I have attached a link to a tutorial. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

Comment: What do you mean by critical values?

Comment: critical point?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your example in the question? What are the critical values?

Comment: in the inequality, the critical value would be x = 0 and x = 1. The way I see it, critical values are values for x of which all the numbers on one side of x cannot be solutions to the inequality. for instance in the example, x =  0 is a critical value because when you use a test points between 0 to 1 (which are numbers on the right side of 0) they do not work in the inequality. So we say x=0 is a critical value.

Comment: Well, it *is* an inequality.  It can't be both bigger and smaller than something at the same time.   I suppose you can do $f(x) = x$ if $x\ge 1$ and $f(x) = \frac 1x$ if $0 < x < 1$.  THen the inequality $\frac 1{f(x)}<1$ will do what you want.

Comment: @fleablood. what are you talking about? I don't follow

Comment: Well, you *are* asking a rather meaningless question.  If $\frac 1x < 1$ then $x<0;x>1$ and there isn't any reason to ask *why* we can't have an $x$ between $0$ and $1$.  That's just not the answer.  I figured you wanted an inequality $f(x)< 1$ with two critical points where $x < 1$ and $x>1$ are solutions. Define $f(x) = \begin{cases}x& x>1\\ \frac 1{1-x}& 0<x<1\end{cases}$. Then the inequality $\frac 1{f(x)} < 1$ will have solutions $0< x < 1$ and $x > 1$.

Comment: The premise of your question, i.e. the observation you make for such inequalities- is itself an issue. for e.g. $1/(x^2+1)<1$ has the variable in denominator, but the solution does not conform to your observation. OTOH, $x<x^2$ has no denominator, but its solutions are outside a closed interval. So the pattern you claim itself is questionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little unclear about your question, as it mentions two critical values (I'm assuming you mean restrictions or non-permissible values) but the inequality you included only has one. However, here are two examples that might address what you're asking:

$$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)^2} > 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{(x+1)^2(x-1)^2} > 0$$

Both the above inequalities have the restrictions $x \neq \pm 1\,$.

The solution for the first is $\,-1 < x < 1\,$ or $\,x>1\,$, i.e. in between the two non-permissible values **and** to the right of the larger one.

The solution to the second is $\,x<-1\,$ or $\,-1 < x < 1\,$ or $\,x>1\,$, i.e. in between the two non-permissible values **and** outside both.

You'll no doubt notice that the difference between the two examples is the power of the $\,(x+1)\,$ factor in the denominator. In general, for  inequalities involving polynomial or rational functions, 'the solutions "change" around zeroes that come from factors with **odd** exponents (or zeroes with odd 'multiplicity', if you're familiar with that term), whereas they don't "change" around zeroes that come from factors with **even** exponents.

Comment: so my observation is incorrect. There can be inequalities where the solution ranges over values on one side of a restriction and also in between the two restriction (critical value) points. Cool, thanks!